# Add additional field to db-data-config.xml in Apache solr

Tags: apache, solr

I need to update the db-data-config.xml file for my solr instance. I am adding the below line:

```
<field column="DOC_NUM_TST" name="docNumFacet" />
```

I have done that, but I don't know how to make sure solr is updated correctly after the change. Do I need to do something more than add the line and restart solr? I have query where ((docNum:*A*)) will return results but ((docNumFacet:"A")) returns nothing.

Comment: Do you have schema.xml file? Did you add the field in solr's schema.xml file?

Comment: Depends how your SOLR is setup.  Ex. if you use SOLR Cloud, you then have a ZooKeeper setup.  Then the configuration file needs to be uploaded to ZK.

Comment: The field is in the schema.xml. I'm not using SOLR cloud

Comment: @Hardrock302 : If you have added the field in the data-config.xml and schema.xml. Make sure you restart the server and re-index the data.